# Making android apps using a locally hosted webserver

Tags: android, python, web-applications

So I want to make an android app that is accessible as a website, but at the same time, I want to release it as an app that is available offline. I was wondering if the following workflow was possible:

- create a website using some sort of python web server (let's assume something like bottle since it doesn't have to be installed - if that works, then I'll try and use something like flask instead).
- run the website on a web server (I know how to do this part)
- For anyone using the android app, they would have a web server hosted on their phones, and they would access it using something along the lines of [android webview](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) (presumably using localhost:someunusedport as the url or something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a horrible and insecure way of doing it.  Putting a webserver on their phones to run an app is insane.  Do you think the average user can secure that?  Do you think that its existance would ever register even if they could?  Are you claiming you're going to provide 0 day support for all bugs?

In addition you'd get 0 of the benefits of running as a native app (performance, integration, improved featureset) because you aren't a native app, you're a webpage.  Yet you wouldn't have the advantages of a webpage (rapid updates, access to more resources than exist on a phone) either.  Its the worst of both worlds.

If you want to make it available offline, make it entirely in html/javascript.  It still won't have either of the advantages, but it won't be running a totally unsecured webserver on his phone just waiting to be hacked.